# Want to align figures

Tags: minipage, alignment, wrapfigure

So I will try to make it as concise as possible.
This is what my code looks like

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{II.Theoretical Concept and state of the art/EOAT/Img/small EOAT.jpg}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
\caption{Small Plastic EOAT}
\end{center}\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm,height=4.5cm]{II.Theoretical Concept and state of the art/EOAT/Img/YbigEOAT.jpg}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
\caption{Fanuc robot arm with mounted EOAT}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

This is how it turned out :

[image: link]

I want to align them so there isn't that height difference. I tried playing with sizes and wasn't successful. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use `\begin{minipage}[t]` so they align at the top.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you looking for the following:

[image]

The simplest way (according to my opinion) is insert images in their captions into table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\hsize=\linewidth}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=1mm}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} C{0.9}  C{1.1} @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    &   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=4.5cm]{example-image-b} \\
\caption{Small Plastic EOAT}
    &   \caption{Fanuc robot arm with mounted EOAT}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number if issues with your code, here are some recommendations and a solution with minipages:

1. Set the `\graphicspath` so you do not need to write `II.Theoretical Concept and state of the art/EOAT/Img/YbigEOAT.jpg`. Do you really have
   such long paths?
2. Your images will look better at same height. Set the `height=` of
   both images to the same height.
3. Align the minipages at `[t]`.
4. Don't do minipage width as `{0.5\textwidth}` you need some space in between
5. Use `\fbox` to visualize.
6. LaTeX needs effortful learning, not trial-and-error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm, skip=3.5pt, font={small}, labelfont={bf}}
\fboxrule=0.2pt
\fboxsep=0pt
\begin{document}
A\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
ga\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{./images/harnett}
  \caption{Small Plastic EOAT}
\end{minipage}}\hspace{5mm}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
  \centering
 \includegraphics[height=4.5cm]{./images/twowomen-03}
\caption{Fanuc robot arm with mounted EOAT}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It makes little sense to specify both width and height.

Let's say that you want to have about 7cm and 7.5cm, but you don't want to specify the length explicitly. What you probably want is that the *ratio* is the same, so one minipage should be 0.483 of the text width and the other 0.517. The pictures will be 95% of the allotted size to ensure some separation.

Use `t`op alignment for the minipages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\setcounter{figure}{15}

\begin{figure}[htp]

\begin{minipage}[t]{.483\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
\caption{Small Plastic EOAT}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.517\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{example-image}
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=0.1cm}
\caption{Fanuc robot arm with mounted EOAT}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for your help.
`\begin{minipage}[t]` and adjusting the size of the pictures a bit gave me what I wanted.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, in answer you change question proposition. There fore -1 for it!

Comment: I'm confused ? what ?